# How to convert row values into column - MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert row values to columns. which means my table has line numbers and sewing machines. It shows which sewing machine in which line numbers.so I want line numbers as columns to show machines on each line. There should be multiple duplicate values and I want to show them all.

Please note - sorry for my bad English

***Existing table (1000+ records)***

| ID | Barcode | Machine_Type | Line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1125 | Zigzag | L01 |
| 2 | 1111 | Zigzag | L01 |
| 3 | 1255 | Puller | L02 |
| 4 | 8569 | Single Needle | L05 |
| 5 | 6589 | Double Needle | L01 |
| 6 | 4589 | RAM | L04 |

***This is the output I want***

| L01 | L02 | L03 | L04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Puller | Zigzag | Zigzag | Single Needle |
| Puller | Double Needle | Zigzag | RAM |
| RAM | RAM | Puller | Zigzag |
| Double Needle | RAM | Single Needle | Double Needle |
| Single Needle | Zigzag | Double Needle | RAM |
| Double Needle | RAM | RAM | Puller |

I tried this but its not giving output as i expected

```
SELECT 
         (CASE WHEN `line` = 'L01' THEN machine_type ELSE null END) AS `Line 1`,
         (CASE WHEN `line` = 'L02' THEN machine_type ELSE null END) AS `Line 2`
  FROM   dr_scan
  WHERE scan_freq=2
```

Please refer attached database table image[image]

Comment: SQL has a strict rule: you MUST know the number & types of columns at query compile time, before looking at **any** data. If you check the data to know about your columns, you won't be able to do this in a single step. Rather, you must run a query to find how many columns you need, use that result to build another query dynamically, and then run the dynamic query. Alternatively, you can try limiting the columns to some reasonable number. Either way, you'll find this kind of `PIVOT` painful, and it's antithetical to the relational set theory behind all SQL databases.

Comment: You need in aggregation. Without it you'd receive the output line for each source line.

Comment: @Akina can you share an example with me?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. But you could you SQL VIEWS here. Refer this answer  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/reshape-a-table-to-convert-rows-to-columns

Comment: *can you share an example with me?*  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot

Comment: The expected output cannot be reconciled back to the sample data. For example, L01 has two zigzag rows in the sample data, but zigzag is shown under L02 and L03 in the expected results. It is also unclear how to determine which item should be in which row in the expected results. You have asked this questiin already and have been told the same things, yet you re-asked the question without any meaningful modifications! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78005469/is-there-anyway-to-remove-null-values-in-the-case-function-of-the-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE IN ADVANCE** 
The OP's expected out is NOT possible based on the sample data provided(which has 6 rows and it is too feeble to account for an output of reasonably rich contents). So the answer here uses an adjusted sample data set, which results a corresponding output.

**THE ANSWER PART STARTS HERE** 
Table pivot can be painful. Here is one of the possible ways to do it. It requires sorting each pivot column with a row number into a table, then performs OUTTER JOIN on those tables using matching row numbers. 
First of all, let's build a base table.

```
create table dr_scan(ID int,    Barcode int,    Machine_Type varchar(20),   Line char(3));

insert dr_scan values
(1,1125,'Zigzag','L01'),
(2,1111,'Zigzag','L01'),
(3,1255,'Puller','L02'),
(4,8569,'Single Needle','L05'),
(5,6589,'Double Needle','L01'),
(6,4589,'RAM','L04'),
(7,7589,'Puller','L04'),
(8,3589,'RAM','L04'),
(9,2589,'Double Needle','L04'),
(10,1589,'RAM','L04');

select * from dr_scan;
-- result 
+------+---------+---------------+------+
| ID   | Barcode | Machine_Type  | Line |
+------+---------+---------------+------+
|    1 |    1125 | Zigzag        | L01  |
|    2 |    1111 | Zigzag        | L01  |
|    3 |    1255 | Puller        | L02  |
|    4 |    8569 | Single Needle | L05  |
|    5 |    6589 | Double Needle | L01  |
|    6 |    4589 | RAM           | L04  |
|    7 |    7589 | Puller        | L04  |
|    8 |    3589 | RAM           | L04  |
|    9 |    2589 | Double Needle | L04  |
|   10 |    1589 | RAM           | L04  |
+------+---------+---------------+------+
```

Now let's determine all the possible pivot columns,which are based on the distinct `line` values:

```
select distinct line from dr_scan order by line;
-- result
+------+
| line |
+------+
| L01  |
| L02  |
| L04  |
| L05  |
+------+
```

Next we shall decide which line has the most row count. Note, getting the count value is optional as it is not required but gives us an idea of the row count of the final pivot table:

```
select line,count(*) ct
from dr_scan
group by line
order by ct desc
limit 1
;
-- result
+------+----+
| line | ct |
+------+----+
| L04  |  5 |
+------+----+
```

Now we know line `L04` has the most rows. Therefore, a derived table named `l4` based on line `L04` shall be used as the leftmost table in a series of LEFT OUTTER JOIN.

```
select l1.machine_type as L01,
l2.machine_type as L02,
l3.machine_type as L03,
l4.machine_type as L04,
l5.machine_type as L05
from        (select line,row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,machine_type
            from dr_scan
            where line='L04') l4
left join  (select line,row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,machine_type
            from dr_scan
            where line='L01') l1
on l4.row_num=l1.row_num
left join  (select line,row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,machine_type
            from dr_scan
            where line='L02') l2
on l4.row_num=l2.row_num
left join  (select line,row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,machine_type
            from dr_scan
            where line='L03') l3
on l4.row_num=l3.row_num
left join  (select line,row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,machine_type
            from dr_scan
            where line='L05') l5
on l4.row_num=l5.row_num
;

-- result
+---------------+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| L01           | L02    | L03  | L04           | L05           |
+---------------+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| Zigzag        | Puller | NULL | RAM           | Single Needle |
| Zigzag        | NULL   | NULL | Puller        | NULL          |
| Double Needle | NULL   | NULL | RAM           | NULL          |
| NULL          | NULL   | NULL | Double Needle | NULL          |
| NULL          | NULL   | NULL | RAM           | NULL          |
+---------------+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
```

With row numbers (based on the sequence of id) defined for each of our line table and the row numbers are used as join condition, the values for each pivot column in the result table is sorted out . Note, in our test sample, there is no `L03` in the `line` column. I wrote it in our query as a placeholder. This also means you can choose which pivot columns you need.

Comment: 1) you need a number of queries to determine which row has the most values 2) output does not match expected results. 2) is strictly speaking not your fault, but could have waited until the OP cleared that up.

Comment: @Shadow, Could you please elaborate on your first point as why we need  a number of queries to determine which row has the most values? And about your 2nd point, I actually used my own sample data to demonstrate, which I think my query output matches the result set based on my sample data.

Comment: You are using a separate query to determine which group has most rows and after that you have to manually assemble the order of the joins. Your query is not going to produce the expected results the OP provided based on the OP's sample data. What it produces based on your data is irrelevant.

Comment: I suppose the OP's expected output is based on the production data which has 1000+ records. In that case, it's impossible to produce the same result using the sample data which merely constitutes a minor part. But it would be too much a hassle for the OP to post the entire dataset, not to mention the potential violation of confidential terms it might impose. However, I do think the OP should take more effort as to produce a expected result based on the sample data provided.

Comment: About the answer I provided, with no possibility to produce the same output the OP expects based on the sample data, I took the liberty of slightly incrementing the sample data as the it has only 6 rows, which is too feeble to account for a reasonable result. I did the explanation in hope it may help the OP learn. And I do believe the my query result based on my tutorial sample data is true.

Comment: Regarding *You are using a separate query to determine which group has most rows and after that you have to manually assemble the order of the joins.* , is there some particular flaw I should notice ? The queries I use do give me a result set which matches my tutorial data. So please enlighten me which part of my answer is faulty. And if it doesn't bother you too much, please directly edit my answer. Your help will definitely be appreciated.

Comment: If there is no way to reproduce the OP's expected result based on the OP's sample data, then you better ask for clarification and flag/vote the question to be claused  if there is no reaction from the OP. Your answer is faulty because it doesnot comply with the OP's expected result. Also, pivoting questions for mysql has been answered so many times including cases with row_number used for grouping.

Comment: Apart from the comliance issue with the OP's expected output, if there is no technical fault with my answer , I think I shall keep it as a tutorial. *Also, pivoting questions for mysql has been answered so many times including cases with row_number used for grouping.* Nowadays at SO (at least for mysql tag) it's hard to open a page without seeing quite a few questions marked as duplicate or closed.  Sometimes people are lenient. Otherwise more duplicate or closed could surface.  As long as an answer helps, I think both the OP and the answer provider benefits. The best way to learn is to teach.

Comment: By the way, I added a **NOTE IN ADVANCE** section at the very beginning to declare the unsoluble issue the OP has made. Hope it helps the OP realise his post needs more clarification.